# Including xhtml files slows down my system

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, facelets

I have menu.xhtml where I include all my xhtml files. Because these files consist of dialogs and should be opened on main page. But when I click a button in menu.xhtml it searches all the files and all controllers start to work. This really slows down my sistem.

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include dialogs in main page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316316/how-to-include-dialogs-in-main-page)

Comment: Please do not ask the same question over and over, this would only work against you. Just edit and improve the question if you think it needs improvement and/or more attention.