# How to include dialogs in main page

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, facelets

I designed all my pages as pop-ups except the main.xhtml. All dialogs are in different xhtml pages. So, I have to include these pages in main page.
    My main page is like:

```
<ui:include src="../pages/dialog1spage.xhtml"/>
<ui:include src="../pages/dialog2spage.xhtml"/>
<h:outputLink onclick="dialog1.show()";/>
<h:outputLink onclick="dialog2.show()";/>
```

However this kind of design really slows down my system. Because when I enter the main page all controllers depending to these dialogs triggered. But I want that It should only enter the  page I clicked.It should not trace all pages I included.

Comment: What do you mean they get triggereD?

Comment: Since every xhtml page has its own java controller, all methods on these controllers start to work.

Comment: No methods start to work until its called. Only the managed beans' constructor gets called.

Comment: So how can I avoid this? It causes a serious performance problem.

Comment: ok please post your managed bean code

Comment: I guess the tricky part is in jsf side. Isn't it?

Comment: No It shouldn't be. If you could post your managed bean then we can see what exactly being called on

Comment: In other words, you're doing expensive DB actions in (post)constructor of backing bean associated with dialog, instead of in a separate backing bean method which is invoked when dialog is actually opened? If so, why exactly? Making the dialog dynamic/lazy should also save a lot.